# VS2015 - Acessando Aplicação pelo Celular

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

Bom dia!

Estou criando uma API para testes no VS2015.

Ao rodar o projeto, ele utilizar o endereço "localhost:32150", fornecido pelo IIS Express.

Caso eu forneça um método pelo meu navegador, ele funciona normalmente, exemplo: "localhost:32150/api/usuarios"

Na necessidade de fazer esse mesmo GET pelo meu aplicativo no celular, alterei o arquivo "applicationhost.config" e alterei a tag Bindings, conforme instruções em outros locais.
A mesma ficou assim.

```
<bindings>
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:32150:*" />
</bindings>
```

Agora, no navegador, caso eu acesse "meuIP:32150" e forneça meu método (api/usuarios) ele me retorna os usuarios.

Porém, ao tentar realizar a mesma requisição pelo meu app no celular (conectado na mesma rede do computador) eu não tenho acesso ao endereço.

Comment: Como você está tentando acessar? Android? e se acessar pelo Browser do ceular? da certo?

Comment: Bom dia @PauloHDSousa

Tanto realizando uma requisição .exchange do RESTTEMPLATE do Android, quanto acessando pelo Browser eu recebo o erro de Connection Timeout

Comment: A porta está liberada no Firewall?

Comment: Passo 1 é abrir ao menos no browser do Android... abre ao menos em outro computador na mesma rede?

Comment: A Porta está liberada @rubStackOverflow.

Paulo, no momento não possuo outro PC em Rede para testar!